# split full arabic name into pieces(SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**in SQL Server:**

i want to split full name like (محمد محمد وائل أبو العز) wh**ich is arabic name thats name found in one column**, and i want to put first name محمد in column name (FirstName) and second name محمد in column name (SecondName), and third name وائل in column name (ThirdName), and Fourth name أبو العزin column name (FourthName)

**put note that** fourth name contsist of tow pieces and this problem may found in first or second or third name

what's your openion in this case

Comment: The hard thing here is handling edge cases like the two words names like "أبو العز", "عبد الرحمن", "فاطمة الزهراء" etc... To solve this you need an arabic name dictionary that has all these variations, so that you can match each word and two words with this dictionary and find out whether it is a valid one word name or two words. You can't handle all these variations manually because you can't count these edge scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

when you execute the following statement

```
SELECT FirstArabicName,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(FirstArabicName,' ','.'),4) 'FName' ,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(FirstArabicName,' ','.'),3) 'SName' ,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(FirstArabicName,' ','.'),2) 'TName' ,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(FirstArabicName,' ','.'),1) 'Sur Name'
FROM gfodatabase2013.dbo.Students
```

it works well with names that have one word only, but
you still have a problem with names that have two words like "Abd AlRahman"
how we can solve this problem?